# what will happen when writing and read Openstack Swift object at the same time

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I am learning [Openstack swift storage](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/getting_started.html). What will happen when updating/writing and reading Openstack Swift object/container at the same time?

Any hints welcomed. Thanks